# Variable in Google Maps infoWindow content fails

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an infoWindow and I want to get the data from a variable, but this code keeps failing whenever I try to run it.

Without the variable, this code works fine:

```
content: "<button onClick="MyObject.joinevent(this.id);" id='"+mid+"' class="join btn btn-primary pull-right">Join Event</button><br/><hr/>"+"<b>Event Title</b> "+eventtitle+"<br/>"+"<b>Event Time</b> "+eventtime+"<br/>"+"<b>Event Duration</b> "+eventduration+"<br/>"+"<b>Event Category</b> "+eventcategory
```

When I assign the content to a variable:

```
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
var kontent = '"<button onClick="MyObject.joinevent(this.id);" id='"+mid+"' class="join btn btn-primary pull-right">Join Event</button><br/><hr/>"+"<b>Event Title</b> "+eventtitle+"<br/>"+"<b>Event Time</b> "+eventtime+"<br/>"+"<b>Event Duration</b> "+eventduration+"<br/>"+"<b>Event Category</b> "+eventcategory';

content: kontent
            });
```

I get `Unexpected token` error in the line `var kontent = ...`

How can I correct my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [infowindows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#add): The InfoWindow constructor takes an InfoWindowOptions object literal, which specifies the initial parameters for displaying the info window.

This means, you need to change this:

```
 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        var kontent = '"<button onClick="MyObject.joinevent(this.id);" id='"+mid+"' class="join btn btn-primary pull-right">Join Event</button><br/><hr/>"+"<b>Event Title</b> "+eventtitle+"<br/>"+"<b>Event Time</b> "+eventtime+"<br/>"+"<b>Event Duration</b> "+eventduration+"<br/>"+"<b>Event Category</b> "+eventcategory';

        content: kontent
 });
```

To:

```
var kontent = '"<button onClick="MyObject.joinevent(this.id);" id='
        "+mid+"
        ' class="join btn btn-primary pull-right">Join Event</button><br/><hr/>"+"<b>Event Title</b> "+eventtitle+"<br/>"+"<b>Event Time</b> "+eventtime+"<br/>"+"<b>Event Duration</b> "+eventduration+"<br/>"+"<b>Event Category</b> "+eventcategory';

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: kontent
});
```

Answer (score 1):

InfoWindow receives a hash. Define your variable outside, then use it as you like:

```
var kontent = "<button onClick="MyObject.joinevent(this.id);" id='"+mid+"' class="join btn btn-primary pull-right">Join Event</button><br/><hr/>"+"<b>Event Title</b> "+eventtitle+"<br/>"+"<b>Event Time</b> "+eventtime+"<br/>"+"<b>Event Duration</b> "+eventduration+"<br/>"+"<b>Event Category</b> "+eventcategory;
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: kontent
            });
```